# laravel duskインストール時にエラーが発生する

Tags: laravel, composer

#### 前提

laravel duskをインストールしようとするとエラーになりました。対処方法などありましたがご教授いただけると助かります。Laravel Framework 9.26.1

```
composer require --dev laravel/dusk
```

※teratailでも同じ質問をしています。
https://teratail.com/questions/kn96jmwhjmt0l8

#### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - laravel/dusk[v5.0.0, ..., v5.0.2] require illuminate/console ~5.7.0|~5.8.0 -> found illuminate/console[v5.7.0, ..., 5.8.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - laravel/dusk v5.0.3 requires illuminate/console ~5.7.0|~5.8.0|~5.9.0 -> found illuminate/console[v5.7.0, ..., 5.8.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - laravel/dusk[5.0.x-dev, ..., v5.11.0] require ext-zip * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's zip extension.
    - Root composer.json requires laravel/dusk ^5.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/dusk[v5.0.0, ..., v5.11.0].

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
    - /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-pdo_mysql.ini
    - /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-sodium.ini
    - /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini
You can also run `php --ini` in a terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
Alternatively, you can run Composer with `--ignore-platform-req=ext-zip` to temporarily ignore these required extensions.
You can also try re-running composer require with an explicit version constraint, e.g. "composer require laravel/dusk:*" to figure out if any version is installable, or "composer require laravel/dusk:^2.1" if you know which you need.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.
```

#### 補足情報（FW/ツールのバージョンなど）

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^8.0.2",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.2",
        "inertiajs/inertia-laravel": "^0.5.4",
        "laravel/framework": "^9.19",
        "laravel/sanctum": "^2.8",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.7",
        "tightenco/ziggy": "^1.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper": "^2.12",
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "laravel/breeze": "^1.11",
        "laravel/pint": "^1.0",
        "laravel/sail": "^1.0.1",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.4",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^6.1",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.5.10",
        "spatie/laravel-ignition": "^1.0",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "^3.7"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-assets --ansi --force"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "allow-plugins": {
            "pestphp/pest-plugin": true
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

環境構築をdockerで行っていたのですが、dockerfileに下記を記載して、laravel duskをインストールしたところうまくいきました。

```
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install libzip-dev
RUN docker-php-ext-install zip
```